# JAVA DOM API Processing inscrution and doctype before XML prolog

Tags: java, api, xslt, dom, doctype

I am working on DOM API in JAVA, i have a problem, how may i add `Precessing Instruction` (XSLT Style Sheet) and `DOCTYPE` (Document type) **after** XML Prolog
each one in new line please?

**e.g :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE FICHES SYSTEM "docform.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet.xsl"?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the DOCTYPE when creating the document, see http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-102161490 which defines a method `createDocumentType` on the implementation to create a DOCTYPE and a method `createDocument` to create a document taking the DOCTYPE as one parameter.

Thus you need

```
DocumentType docType = implementation.createDocumentType("FICHES", null, "docform.dtd");
Document doc = implementation.createDocument(null, "FICHES", docType);
```

That way you now have a DOM document `doc` with a DOCTYPE node and a root element named `FICHES`, then you can create and insert the processing instruction:

```
doc.insertBefore(doc.createProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"stylesheet.xsl\""), doc.getDocumentElement());
```

Comment: Thank you Martin, but after testing DocumentType does not work, no doctype declaration at all.

And for Processing Inscruction it worked but it was added in the same line with XML Prolog.

Comment: I did not see that requirement of the new line, that might be difficult to achieve, given that the DOM API I think does not allow inserting white space before the root element for formatting. As for the DOCTYPE, how do you check that there is no doctype at all? I think you need to use an LSSerializer to write the DOM document, using a default transformer might not output any DOCTYPE as XSLT does not know that node type.